# My RDD change his values himself

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a basic RDD[Object] on which i apply a map with a hashfunction on Object values using nextGaussian and nextDouble scala function. And when i print values there change at each print

```
def hashmin(x:Data_Object, w:Double) = {
    val x1 = x.get_vector.toArray
    var a1 = Array(0.0).tail
    val b = Random.nextDouble * w

    for( ind <- 0 to x1.size-1) {
        val nG = Random.nextGaussian
        a1 = a1 :+ nG
    }

    var sum = 0.0

    for( ind <- 0 to x1.size-1) {
        sum = sum + (x1(ind)*a1(ind))
    }           

    val hash_val = (sum+b)/w

    val hash_val1 = (x.get_id,hash_val)
    hash_val1
}


val w = 8
val rddhash = parsedData.map(x => hashmin(x,w))
rddhash.foreach(println)
rddhash.foreach(println)
```

I don't understand why. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RDDs are merely a "pointer" to the data + operations to be applied to it. Actions materialize those operations by executing the RDD lineage.

So, RDDs are basically recomputed when an action is requested. In this case, the map function calling `hashmin` is being evaluated every time the `foreach` action is called.

There're few options:

- Cache the RDD - this will cause the lineage to be broken and the results of the first transformation will be preserved:

  `val rddhash = parsedData.map(x => hashmin(x,w)).cache()`
- Use a seed for your random function, sothat the pseudo-random sequence generated is each time the same.

Comment: First option does not resolive the problem if rdd is being recomputed for example due to lack off sufficient memory.

Comment: @user52045 you will need to use the alternative method 'persist(...)'  and provide storage level. `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER`.  `cache` is a shorthand for `persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY). But in general it should serve the purpose.

Comment: From what i understand this minimise recomputation but there is no guarantee it wont be recomputed at all.

Answer (score 0):

RDDs are lazy - they're computed when they're used. So the calls to `Random.nextGaussian` are made again each time you call `foreach`.

You can use [`persist()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) to store an RDD if you want to keep fixed values.